# Travis testing with production database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Travis is connecting to my database on heroku despite creating a database in `travis.yml`

```
before_script:
  - psql -c 'CREATE database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
```

This is how I connect to my database

```
class Database {
  constructor() {
    const config = {
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    };
    this.client = new Client(config);
    this.client.connect();
  }
```

Everything works fine locally and on heroku but I don't want travis to connect to the heroku database and add/delete rows as the tests might specify. How do I get travis to use it's database? And how do I create tables for the travis database?

Comment: Do you have environment variables in travis (they can be set in travis.yml, or the interface)? It would appear you have one named DATABASE_URL.

Comment: You can also run `heroku pg:reset` to change your database credentials. That will automatically reset your DATABASE_URL, but if travis has a copy, it will then have invalid values.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I removed the env variable on travis and it worked for a while. Now my tests are returning 500 and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Probably because the database isn't setup. Try reproducing locally.

Comment: The db works. It was a token problem